# Fail2Ban regex does not match

Tags: regex

I'm using fail2ban. For some reason Fail2Ban refuse to compile my regex. Here is my logs that I need to match:

```
root@server1:/etc/fail2ban/filter.d# tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sun Apr 20 10:40:05 2014] [error] [client 75.144.181.151] user root: authentication failure for "/phpmyadmin/": Password Mismatch
[Sun Apr 20 10:40:16 2014] [error] [client 75.144.181.151] user root: authentication failure for "/phpmyadmin/": Password Mismatch
[Sun Apr 20 10:40:38 2014] [error] [client 75.144.181.151] user haker not found: /phpmyadmin/
[Sun Apr 20 10:40:44 2014] [error] [client 75.144.181.151] user pentest not found: /phpmyadmin/
```

and here is my fail2ban **filter.d** file:

```
root@server1:/etc/fail2ban/filter.d# cat /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf
[Definition]
failregex = [client <HOST>;] user .*; not found: \/phpmyadmin\/|[client <HOST>;] user root: authentication failure for "\/phpmyadmin\/":
ignoreregex =
```

here is my regex line from the file above:

```
[client <HOST>;] user .*; not found: \/phpmyadmin\/|[client <HOST>;] user root: authentication failure for "\/phpmyadmin\/":
```

Unfortunately fail2ban log file giving me error about regex: **Unable to compile regular expression..**

```
root@server1:/etc/fail2ban# tail /var/log/fail2ban.log
2014-04-20 10:47:06,788 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/apache2/error.log
2014-04-20 10:47:06,789 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 3
2014-04-20 10:47:06,789 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2014-04-20 10:47:06,790 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
2014-04-20 10:47:06,790 fail2ban.filter : ERROR  Unable to compile regular expression '[client (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\w\-.^_]+);] user .*; not found: \/phpmyadmin\/|[client (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\w\-.^_]+);] user root: authentication failure for "\/phpmyadmin\/":'
2014-04-20 10:47:06,794 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' started
2014-04-20 10:47:06,799 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'pureftpd' started
2014-04-20 10:47:06,805 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'phpmyadmin' started
```

My regex http://regex101.com/r/kU7tX3. What is wrong with this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You'd surely need to escape those `[` and `]` in the regex.

Comment: I change it to `\[client <HOST>;\] user .*; not found: \/phpmyadmin\/|\[client <HOST>;\] user root: authentication failure for "\/phpmyadmin\/":` Fail2Ban still not compile..

Answer (score 0):

I would have asked a question in comment but i cannot add a comment:

So trying my best to understand the requirement and giving an answer.

Requirement: I think you are looking to filter all lines containing
"authentication failure for "/phpmyadmin/""

You can do so by changing your regular expression to following:

```
failregex = .*authentication failure for "\/phpmyadmin\/"
```

You may have to escape "

Please add comments if this wasn't the correct understanding.....

Comment: IP address is also required because Fail2Ban need to ban by IP. So I change it to `failregex = \[client <HOST>;\] .*authentication failure for "\/phpmyadmin\/"` and now fail2Ban would compile successfully but not banned the IP address. I think regex does not match with the log...